# Connect TaskFactory to RESTful service to push data from Salesforce into SOA services

Tags: rest-service

Does anyone have any experience with using Pragmatic Works TaskFactory SSIS software to connect to and pull data from Salesforce, and if so do you know if it's possible to configure TaskFactory to push data to a RESTful service as opposed to having to map the Salesforce object fields directly to database tables/columns?

Comment: Why do you need TaskFactory?
You can simply use DataLoader to retrieve data from Salesforce or insert or update or delete data from Salesforce

Comment: What is DataLoader?